# How to write unit test case for form.dirty in Angular 7

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How to write unit test case for  form.dirty in Angular 7?

```
  revertChanges(): void {
    if (!!this.form && this.form.dirty) {
      console.log("Demo")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to use the markAsDirty() method on your form, execute the component method and spyOn the return value ?